# How to implement caching for nested methods in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, outputcache

Suppose i have a following function

```
 public JsonResult FunctionA(int a, int b)
    {
        int c = 1;// Dynamic Value
        return Json(FunctionB(a, b, c));
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public string FunctionB(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        // Some calculation
        return "result";
    }
```

will the output caching works for **FunctionB** that is called inside **FunctionA**.

I cannot use any other third party library for the scenario. If my approach is incorrect please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no. The OutputCache attribute is part of the MVC pipeline. It enables the web server to store the output from an action method in memory, so if a view is returned from a method on a controller, the view page will be cached and served up until the cached version expires.

If you want to cache operations internal to your application, you'll have to either roll your own caching or use a 3rd party componenent (I'm aware of your limitation with regards to third party libraries but caching is very easy to get wrong).

There are some tools and guidelines out there to help you achieve that.

Comment: could you please throw some tools and guidelines in?